# Can't call controller function from view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call the controller function from view.
This my view:

```
   <body>
   <div ng-app="appTable">
      <div ng-controller="Allocation">
         <button ng-click="add()"> Add </button> 
         <button ng-click="remove()">remove</button>
         <table>
            <th>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Project</td>
            <td>Release</td>
            <td>Feature</td>
            <td>Module name</td>
            <td>Hours spent</td>
            <td>Comment</td>
            </th>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
               <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.isDelete"/></td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text"
                     datepicker
                     ng-model="data.date" />                 
               </td>
               <td><input type="text" ng-model="data.dept"/></td>
               <td>
                  <select ng-model="data.release" ng-options="x for x in range">
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <select ng-model="data.feature" ng-options="x for x in feature">
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type = "text" ng-model = "data.modulename">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <select ng-model="data.hours" ng-options="x for x in hours">
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type = "text" ng-model = "data.comment">
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <button ng-click="Submit()">Submit</button>
         <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in displayList">
               <div ng-controller="Allocation as vm">
                  <div>{{vm.postdata(data.date)}}</div>
               </div>
               <p>Output Message : {{msg}}</p>
               <p>StatusCode: {{statusval}}</p>
               <p>Status: {{statustext}} </p>
               <p>Response Headers: {{headers}} </p>
               <td>
                  <p>{{data.date}}</p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p>{{data.dept}}</p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p>{{data.release}}</p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p>{{data.feature}} </p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p>{{data.modulename}}</p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p>{{data.hours}}</p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p>{{data.comment}}</p>
               </td>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

This is script.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("appTable", []);

    app.controller("Allocation", function($scope) {
        $scope.hours = ["1", "2", "3"];
        $scope.range = ["1", "2", "3"];
        $scope.feature = ["UT", "FSDS", "Coding/Devlopment", "QA"];

        $scope.dataList = [{
            date: '17/07/2016',
            dept: 'OneCell',
            release: '1',
            feature: "UT",
            modulename: "Redundancy",
            hours: "1",
            comment: "Add extra information"
        }];

        $scope.add = function() {
            var data = {};
            var size = $scope.dataList.length;
            if (!size) {
                $scope.dataList = [{
                    date: '17/07/2016',
                    dept: 'OneCell',
                    release: '1',
                    feature: "UT",
                    modulename: "Redundancy",
                    hours: "1",
                    comment: "Add extra information"
                }];
            } else {
                size = size - 1;
                data.date = $scope.dataList[size].date;
                data.dept = $scope.dataList[size].dept;
                data.release = $scope.dataList[size].release;
                data.feature = $scope.dataList[size].feature;
                data.modulename = $scope.dataList[size].modulename;
                data.hours = $scope.dataList[size].hours;
                data.comment = $scope.dataList[size].comment;
                $scope.dataList.push(data);
            }

        };

        $scope.Submit = function() {
            $scope.test = "Submit is pressed...";
            $scope.displayList = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.dataList, function(v) {
                if (!v.isDelete) {
                    $scope.displayList.push(v);
                }
            });
            $scope.dataList.splice(0);


        };
        $scope.remove = function() {
            var newDataList = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.dataList, function(v) {
                if (!v.isDelete) {
                    newDataList.push(v);
                }
            });
            $scope.dataList = newDataList;
        };

        $scope.postdata = function(date) {

            var data = {
                date: date,
            };
            $http.post('/add_status/', data).then(function(response) {
                if (response.data)
                    $scope.msg = "Post Data Submitted Successfully!";
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.msg = "Service not Exists";
                $scope.statusval = response.status;
                $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
                $scope.headers = response.headers();
            });
        };


    });


    app.directive("datepicker", function() {

        function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            // CALL THE "datepicker()" METHOD USING THE "element" OBJECT.
            element.datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dt) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        // UPDATE THE VIEW VALUE WITH THE SELECTED DATE.
                        controller.$setViewValue(dt);

                    });
                },
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" // SET THE FORMAT.
            });
        }

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link
        };
    });
</script>
```

As you can see in the view I have called the postdata function of the controller.This function internally uses msg variable.But view is not printing value of this variable.I am very new to Aj. Please help.

Comment: What does *I want to call controller function from view* mean? This question is not clear

Comment: I have postdata() function in my controller.I want to call this function from my view i.e. from HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make following changes:

1. Remove `ng-controller="Allocation as vm"`, as you already defined controller above., and you not using `this` syntax in controller.
2. after you removed `as vm`, then no need to `vm.` calls.
3. you need to inject `$http` in your controller., to make API call

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tc0q8doh/) demo, I logged dummy text in console for each `submit click.

and to make single call on submit, See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9jtmjzv/)

Comment: I have tried that also,without using ng-controller="Allocation as vm",it prints function name as it is in output,like {{postdata(data.date)}}

Comment: @spaceearth: you also need to inject `$http` in your controller, to make API calls, I edited my answer. check the fiddle link also

Comment: I have seen your fiddle demo.But it is printing the Output Message,status code... empty.How to see console log in fiddle?

Comment: @spaceearth : because I've commented the `$http.post` call, since I don't have your API. further if possible don't make `post` call on each iteration, try to accumulate your data and make 1 call

Comment: I it is working.But it is continuously calling function.I want functionality like when submit button is called then only postData() function should be called. What should be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144254/discussion-between-anoop-and-space-earth).

Answer (score 0):

You should return a value in the function or add a scope variable to be shown in the controller's div, because right now you are not showing anything.

```
<div ng-controller="Allocation as vm">
                  <div>{{vm.postdata(data.date)}}</div>
               <p>Output Message : {{msg}}</p>
               <p>StatusCode: {{statusval}}</p>
               <p>Status: {{statustext}} </p>
               <p>Response Headers: {{headers}} </p>
</div>
```

Anyway, you should not run procedural function in this way. Bind it to an event, ng-click or something.

And do not create other than `td` or `th` child elements in `tr`.

This is the proper html table structure:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Month</th>
   <th>Savings</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>January</td>
   <td>$100</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This thing is already I have done in my code.But it is not working

Comment: @spaceearth if you resolved all the three issue I mentioned and still don't work, you should create an mcve to be easier to see what the problem is.